# Sync my svn repositories

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, svn

I use my own svn repositories for all my development.  I am looking for an easy way to keep the svn repository wordpress provides for my plugin synced up with my own internal repository.  The desired end result being that when I commit a change to my own internal repository it gets duplicated automatically to my repository at plugins.svn.wordpress.org.

ANd just to make things fun and interesting, I do not have any access to the server where my svn repositorys are held, I use a svn hosting service.

Comment: Are you using SVN in combination with other software like an operating system and a shell (on your client system)? What is the name and the features of that SVN hosting service (URL?)?

Comment: You need to ask codespaces.com for that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the svn switch -- relocate repository option can help you here: svn switch --relocate oldURL newURL . ( http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html )

But... a lot more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580443/svn-one-working-copy-two-repositories

Answer (score 6):

Subversion doesn't work that way.  You have a local copy and a repository ... only two systems.  There's no concept of syncing a local copy to a local repository *and* a remote repository.

I recommend you look into using either Git or Mercurial for your local development.  Both systems allow you to have a local repository (for local source control) as well as pushing to a remote repository.

Both of these *distributed version control* systems can integrate with Subversion as well.  So you build locally, commit to a local repository (or on your own server), then push to WordPress.org's Subversion repository when you've reached a convenient release point.

There are a few good Git-Svn tutorials floating around the Internet that deal specifically with WordPress plugin development.  [Here's one](http://www.nicolaskuttler.com/post/using-git-for-wordpress-development/).  Using Mercurial follows some of the same patterns.

Comment: Yes, there is an easier way ... the way I suggested using either Git or Hg.  You can always "write a program" to do just about anything ... but then you're not using Subversion to do the synchronization, you're using your own program.

Comment: SVN has not two but one system. But that's only a note in the margin :)